# Is "by nature, for nature" right

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, subjects

I am creating a tagline for a vegetable and fruit brand. I want to tell people that the produce is (or products are) created through natural practices, for the betterment of the environment. So I propose "by nature, for nature".

This tagline is rejected by my partner, as he thinks, the subjects are inconsistent in this context. Subject for "by nature" is "produces", subject for "for nature" is "the way to produce". So I cannot use it this way.

Can someone help me to explain this to him?

Comment: The slogan BY NATURE, FOR NATURE is fine. But your question ** Subject for "by nature" is "produces", subject for "for nature" is "the way to produce". So I can not use it this way. ** is NOT clear.

Comment: One slight problem you might face is that the slogan "By nature for nature" [has been thought of already](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=%22by+nature+for+nature%22)

Answer (score 0):

As a tag line or title, where brevity is accepted as more important than strict grammar, it’s valid. I wouldn’t recommend it in prose for the reason your partner gives.

As @MichaelHarvey commented, another company has already used it, which is solid evidence that it’s acceptable. However, the possible legal complications that brings are out of scope here.